# glReadPixel pixel color

Tags: opengl, sdl

```
void render(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f( 0, 255, 0 ); //color it green
glVertex3f( -100, 0,  100  );
glVertex3f( -100, 0, -100  );
glVertex3f( 100,  0, -100 );
glVertex3f( 100,  0, 100 );
glEnd();

int tmpx, tmpy;
GLint pixel_color[3];
SDL_GetMouseState(&tmpx, &tmpy);

glReadPixels(tmpx, win_width - tmpy, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_INT , &pixel_color[0]);
printf("PIXEL: %d - %d - %d\n", pixel_color[0], pixel_color[1], pixel_color[2]);

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}
```

Using the render code above, I am trying to get the rgb color of the pixel pointed by the mouse. The plane is coloured full green(255) but the value returned by the glReadPixels is 2147483647 instead of 255.

I already tried changing types but it never returned the value I expected. How can I make it return the same value set by glColor?

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
GLint pixel_color[3];
```

to

```
GLubyte pixel_color[3];
```

and change

```
glReadPixels(tmpx, win_width - tmpy, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_INT , &pixel_color[0]);
```

to

```
glReadPixels(tmpx, win_width - tmpy, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , &pixel_color[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but, it only returns 0 or 255. What I want to get is the exact same value set in glColor(). Like if I set green to 175, I also get 175 in the pixel color returned by glReadPixels. Is that possible? How?

Comment: It works for me just as you are describing, no idea why it wouldn't work :/

Comment: @markuz: glColor3f clamps the given values to the range [0;1]. You want to use glColor3b instead.

Comment: Alternatively, use glColor3f(0/255.0,175/255.0,0/255.0); =)

Comment: @JariKomppa that does it! :) Thank you. But,I don't get it :p, if it's ok with you, could you give a little explanation why is it needed to divide it by 255?

Comment: glColor3f eats floats, and the values must be in the range of 0..1. Outside this, the values are clamped to 0..1.